# Count already used ids pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a problem where i need to count already used ids. In my data set there are attributes: `id, time, Bi` witch looks something like this:

```
id   time   Bi   | wanted_results    used
1     3     NAN  |       0           []
1     3      1   |       1           [1] 
1     2     NAN  |       1           [1] 
2     2      1   |       2           [1, 2]
2     1      1   |       2           [1, 2] 
2     1      1   |       2           [1, 2]
```

Attribute description:

- `id` - represents what we count
- `time` - is used for timeline, witch
  goes from `n to 0`
- `Bi` - represents if id was used in that time
- `used` - stands for representation of what was counted

So now i want unique already used ids as a count.
How can i group data to store used ids, to get wanted results?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You can use a combination of expanding and apply.

```
df['id'].expanding().apply(lambda x: len(np.unique(x)))
```

This will return a Series with the results you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by iterating over the `DataFrame` and adding the `id`s to a `set`

```
df['wanted_result'] = 0
used_set = set()
for row in df.itertuples():
    df.loc[row.Index, 'wanted_result'] = len(used_set)
    used_set.add((row.id,))
```

Results in

```
  id  time   Bi   wanted_result
0  1  3      NAN  0
1  1  3      1    1
2  1  2      NAN  1
3  2  2      1    1
4  2  1      1    2
5  2  1      1    2
```